# How to Write SEO friendly blog posts

Tags: blog, websites

How can I write blog posts that are SEO (*search engine optimization*) friendly? I know there is lots of content available out there,
but I want to know how to start writing the post as SEO friendly.

Comment: It fits, because many of us do most of our writing online, whether professionally or for fun.

Comment: First, use an appropriate title.  It's not "How to Write SEO friendly blog posts", it's "Boost Traffic to Your Blog with this One Weird Trick!"

Comment: People write books (and websites) about this. It's far too general a question, and depends on a lot of factors - if your blog is about cryptocurrency, techniques will likely be different than if you're writing a personal blog about your life, or knitting tips, or posting music. And what language is it in, what are the posts like, what are you selling, what's your audience, all basic questions for SEO.

Answer (score 9):

What is the main topic?  As algorithms change, one of the best things to do is consistently "write like a human."  Just talk about Your Topic, and do it frequently.  More words = more chances for the Right Words to ping.

Since I'm doing a podcast, for the one where I'm fully scripting it, I'm including that script/transcript as a chance for Google and other search engines to have more words to find.

(I say "words" though any Original Content is what the search engines should be focused on, but I know words better than other elements.  But if you do photos/video, while they can have most of the "originality" of the site's content, make sure that the key information is echoed in words. )

From https://www.blogtyrant.com/beginner-blogging-seo/

> the most important thing you can do for your SEO is create massively useful content that solves people’s problems. If you are solving problems that people are searching for then it is likely that you are going to get shared on social media and ranked in Google

For strong links (Google was originally called [BackRub](https://www.howtogeek.com/trivia/what-was-googles-original-name/) because the algorithm was all about who trusted you!) , there's not a great shortcut -- you have to build strong relationships with other strong sources.   Again, knowing your topic would help -- can you meet some relevant people at a conference?

Another thing to help with strong content (and readers who stick around) is to have a series: try to become "a habit, not a resource" - like one  episode of *Audacity to Podcast* mentioned.

from https://www.blogtyrant.com/blogger-seo-secrets/

> Returning readers indicate safety... I’d really start to tone down on the small “update” posts and just release big beautiful articles with lots of useful information ... One way to get people back is to produce a series of posts on the same topic

and from https://www.blogtyrant.com/7-things-google-wants-to-see-on-your-blog/

> [This update] changed the way Google looked at searches so they no longer emphasize keywords but instead look at the intention behind the search. For example, people searching for “acid reflux” might really be looking for “why do I have acid reflux?“, “what drugs treat acid reflux?“, etc.

Basically, it's not about keyword stuffing any more.

A resource I've loved for a long time is https://NNGroup.com/articles -- though the articles aren't as directly focused on SEO (and the older ones assume it *is* keyword stuffing), good usability strategies help with SEO.

For example, in 
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/web-writing-use-search-keywords/ , Jakob Neilsen writes:

> Old words rule because people know them intimately.  Familiar words spring to mind unbidden. Thus, users are likely to employ old words when they boil down their problem to a search query, which is typically only 2-3 words long.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, and a virtual +1 for quoting NNGroup.

Comment: Yup, write ahead of the algorithms. The goal of algorithms, not just Google, but Bing and DDG, is to find things that the human will be interested in. They eventually punish dirty tricks. The easiest way is just to write as you would to a human.

Answer (score -1):

Search engine algorithms are going to give your site a better rank

if the page titles, web addresses and page descriptions reflect content.

If you research keywords using Google’s free webmaster tool for AdWord comparisons.

If your content is broken into sections and the subheadings are descriptive.

I coordinated a high profile government site and it is a successful SEO project.